# Unable to receive POST values on ubuntu machine

Tags: php, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, apache2

This is a pretty weird issue. I am sending values to a server as POST, but the server is not receiving them. I recently setup the server on amazon ec2. I've installed ubuntu 3.13.0-44, apache 2.4, php5

**What am I sending?**

A simple value via POST to my server. Via the REST console plugin in chrome

**What is the code on my server?**

$_POST["var"];

Any clues as to what am I missing here?

**Update**

Access log :

14.99.0.122 - - [12/Jul/2015:14:02:52 +0000] "POST /reco/add_user_affiliation_to_neo HTTP/1.1" 404 231 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36"

What I'm sending to the server :

I am using the REST CONSOLE plugin for chrome.

Request Method : POST

**BODY**

Content Headers

Content-type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Request Payload : var=testvalue

Comment: Show the full post sent command and some lines from your apache access log

Comment: I have updated the answer with these values. Please check.

Comment: Can you show us the code on the server and the Response headers ? please

Answer (score 0):

Please check the value of this parameter in your `php.ini`.

> post_max_size

You can't use a value like "8MB" because of that :

> The use of “MB” instead of “M” was invalid, but instead of throwing an
>   error on startup, PHP internally interpreted this as a “0” since it
>   was invalid. Since the post_max_size was effectively zero, nothing
>   made it into the $_POST array.

Hope it will help.

Comment: Your totally right, i edit my post with a global answer. Thx ! :D

Comment: Thanks for the link, but it didn't help my case. I have a default php.ini file and the post_max_size value is 8M.